# Best approach to implement rest service in .net for real-time mobile apps

Tags: c#, android, wcf, asp.net-web-api, real-time-updates

I have to create a service in .net for real-time mobile application in android. 
I have gone through lots of blogs and articles like

[Broadcasting Events with a Duplex WCF Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service)

[Introduction to SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

[Real-Time Web Apps Made Easy with WebSockets in .NET 4.5](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1210051)

[Using websockets in native iOS and Android apps](http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps)

[What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)

There are lots of options I found like,

SignalR, WebSockets, Wcf with wsDualHttpbinding/callback service, GCM push notifications

I think SignalR is just works with .net clients

With GCM push notifications max size allowed is 4k and also mobile apps would ignore the notifications.

I am confused about which is the better approch to use in service with considering android client. If I get some suggetion then it would save my lots of time reading and comparing all the things and I can go deep in one of the better approaches.

Answer (score 2):

SignalR implements a range of protocols including Websocks, forever frame, long polling, and server sent events. The idea behind SignalR is to automatically choose the best communication method regardless of the platform it is used on.

By relying on SignalR to make the choice for you, you are free to focus on the application you are writing rather than worrying about compatibility between devices.

This, combined with the ease of implementation and wide range of support, makes it a great starting point for what you are trying to achieve